# Postman Form-Data not working Validation Failed node js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, postman

I’m facing some problems when using postman. When I try to send raw data in JSON(application/json) format, it gets success. But when I try to send form data, it returns some error.

Comment: how do you expect someone here to what is that "some error" please add the relevant errors

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ExpressJS, you can use the Library multer

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
router.put('/gpu/:pn', upload.none(), gpuController.updateGPU);
```

The above is an example where I was having issues with form-data. After adding the upload.none() I was able to receive the body in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Postman is sending the data as the raw format is working fine. But I don't think you'll get form-data in req.body directly. You need to use request body parser for it!

You can use `body-parser` middleware.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Which is very common. It parses incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property. It does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature.